# problems when installing cloud foundry sts and eclipse integration

Tags: cloud-foundry

I tried to install the Cloud Foundry Integration Extension in STS and in Eclipse exactly followed instructions, but got "MD5 hash is not as expected" problems in both installations.

For STS (3.2.0), I did
1. Launch STS, open Dashboard, click Extentions tab
2. Under Server and Clouds, check "Cloud Foundry Integration for Eclipse" (which is the only checkbox available).
3. Click "Install"
then I got:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.cloudfoundry.ide.eclipse.server,1.4.0.201302222117-RELEASE.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: e693ee5b7151c7f0117230da1d180e8c and found dfa4de929d56da0a5fefd3c1038cd839.

For Eclipse (Juno)
1. Select Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
2. Type "cloud foundry" in the Find box and click "Go"
3. Click Install for "Cloud Foundry Integration for Eclipse" 
4. Confirm feature "Cloud Foundry Integration for Eclipse"
5. Click Finish
then got this error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, 
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: 
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.cloudfoundry.ide.eclipse.server,
1.4.0.201302222117-RELEASE.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: e693ee5b7151c7f0117230da1d180e8c and 
found 9370ec785777f7c2bb1f6982b68df921.

Thanks a lot for your help!!!